# Phaser2 game is not working in mobile but working in browser

Tags: phaser-framework

I have created game with phaser2 its working desktop browser but not working in android, I generated apk with cordova and used crosswalk-webview to improve performance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Is there a specific reason you're using Phaser2 instead of updating to the newest version? A lot of compatibility issues are not ported backwards when an update is released. 

Also, providing more information like any errors, code snippets or reference materials to your issue should help generate more interest in your question and therefore produce better answers.

Comment: Does your game work correctly when you put it all on an HTTP server and try it on a mobile browser? Without any specific error message from the log or console, it's hard to say what is causing the game not to show in your Cordova and Crosswalk setup; lots of "moving parts" so to speak.

Comment: Btw perfectly fine to use Phaser2 imho, it's good library with lots of examples, and Phaser3 still has some missing features (buttons and scalemanager)

Comment: Small correction; I just noticed that Phaser3 has an improved scale manager since early this year.

Comment: Please check this repo https://github.com/nazimboudeffa/dice-mania-cordova-app